# No api proxy found for service "memcache" GAE unittest2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, unittest2

I'am trying to write tests to my app. I make a simple test case:

```
def test_put(self):
    Result(
        id="23738",
        target_id="23738",
    ).put()
```

and after running, it raises an error:

> AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "memcache"

I don't know, how to fix it.

And this is my set_up:

```
def set_up(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
    self.testbed.init_user_stub()
```

and tear_down:

```
def tear_down(self):
    self.testbed.deactivate()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function names in your code are:

```
def set_up(self):
   ...

def tear_down(self):
   ...
```

However, according to the [Python unittest documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), the proper names are [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) and [`tearDown`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) (note the lack of underscore and camelCase).

You can see similar uses of the functions in the [AppEngine Python local unit testing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting).